# Number of bounding boxes in Tensorflow Object detection module

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api, pre-trained-model

I'm doing inference using one of the pre-trained models, tensorflow object detection. However, the train config of the model limits the number of detections to just 5 boxes. Any idea on how to change this parameter during inference?

The model i'm using is the one trained on [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md#inaturalist-species-trained-models). It's config is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_fgvc.config), and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet50_fgvc.config). The max_total_detection is set to 5 here. I'm not sure how to update this to get more number of updates.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

I have tried loading the graph and seeing the variables in the pretrained model. I found a variable that says "num_detections", but I'm not sure how to re-assign it with any of the codes that helps in inference.

During inference, I use the code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb)

I add the following line:

```
num_detections = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
sess.run(tf.assign(num_detections, num_detections+10),feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image,0)})
```

But it gives me an error saying the variable doesn't have any assign attribute. I'm assuming it's because I can't change it.

Is there any other way I can update it? Or would I need to re-train it?

Edit: The first answer worked! Retraining it for 1 num_steps with the changed number boxes in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to a lager `num_detections:0`, you can add a positive integer number to it. But I think you may fail to do that, since you load a frozen graph which one  should not change values of weights and parameters.

Secondly, you can't change the numbers of boxes, even though you change the value of `num_detections:0`. Because how many boxes are kept is determined on NMS step before `num_detection` operation. So you just change wrong variable. I can not help you to find the right variable. Sorry for that.

Finally, you can change the number of `max_total_detections` in the model's config file to keep more bounding boxes. If you don't want to train the model, you can change the config file, train 0 steps and save the model.

Anyone have a better solution?

Comment: I tried finding something similar to ```max_total_detections``` but it wasn't there in the variables. So i'm assuming that's something I cannot set again.

Thank you so much for the retraining idea with 0 steps idea. I didn't know one could do that! I'll definitely give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Posting an update! The method worked fine. Except that you have to give atleast 1 training step! So that's essentially retraining a model from the checkpoint with one more training step.